# Writing unit tests for stripe webhooks stripe-signature

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, stripe-payments

I'm trying to write unit tests for Stripe webhooks. The problem is I'm also verifying the `stripe-signature` and it fails as expected.

Is there a way to pass a correct signature in tests to the webhook with mock data?

This is the beginning of the webhook route I'm trying to handle

```
// Retrieve the event by verifying the signature using the raw body and secret.
let event: Stripe.Event;
const signature = headers["stripe-signature"];

try {
  event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(
    raw,
    signature,
    context.env.stripeWebhookSecret
  );
} catch (err) {
  throw new ResourceError(RouteErrorCode.STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SIGNATURE_VERIFICATION_FAILD);
}

// Handle event...
```

And the current test I'm trying to handle, I'm using Jest:

```
const postData = { MOCK WEBHOOK EVENT DATA }

const result = await request(app.app)
  .post("/webhook/stripe")
  .set('stripe-signature', 'HOW TO GET THIS SIGNATURE?')
  .send(postData);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the help of Nolan I was able to get the signature working. In case anyone else needs help, this is what I did:

```
import { createHmac } from 'crypto';

const unixtime = Math.floor(new Date().getTime() / 1000);

// Calculate the signature using the UNIX timestamp, postData and webhook secret
const signature = createHmac('sha256', stripeWebhookSecret)
  .update(`${unixtime}.${JSON.stringify(postData)}`, 'utf8')
  .digest('hex');

// Set the stripe-signature header with the v1 signature
// v0 can be any value since its not used in the signature calculation
const result = await request(app.app)
  .post("/webhook/stripe")
  .set('stripe-signature', `t=${unixtime},v1=${signature},v0=ff`)
  .send(postData);
```

Comment: Even this approach can resolve the problem but it should avoid because we do it by hand, should use the above answer instead.

Comment: This also works for non Stripe webhooks.

Answer (score 19):

Stripe now exposes a function in its node library that they recommend for creating signatures for testing:

> **Testing Webhook signing**
>
> You can use `stripe.webhooks.generateTestHeaderString` to mock webhook events that come from Stripe:

```
const payload = {
  id: 'evt_test_webhook',
  object: 'event',
};

const payloadString = JSON.stringify(payload, null, 2);
const secret = 'whsec_test_secret';

const header = stripe.webhooks.generateTestHeaderString({
  payload: payloadString,
  secret,
});

const event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(payloadString, header, secret);

// Do something with mocked signed event
expect(event.id).to.equal(payload.id);
```

ref: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node#webhook-signing

Comment: This is the best answer because it comes from official docs, and we don't need to build the signature by our hand which can break our tests when Stripe changes the internal way to build signature.

Answer (score 2):

If you are in ruby you can do:

```
      Stripe::Webhook::Signature.generate_header(
        Time.now,
        Stripe::Webhook::Signature.compute_signature(
          Time.now,
          payload,
          secret
        )
      )
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Python, you can create the signature header like this:

```py
import time
import stripe

def generate_header(payload: str, secret: str) -> str:
    timestamp = int(time.time())
    scheme = stripe.WebhookSignature.EXPECTED_SCHEME
    payload_to_sign = f"{timestamp}.{payload}"
    signature = stripe.WebhookSignature._compute_signature(payload_to_sign, secret)
    return f"t={timestamp},{scheme}={signature}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I landed here trying to setup an integration test in Rails, and just to add to Niels Kristian's answer with a bit more surrounding code I landed on the following (rework the params as needed, and add the actual `STRIPE_ENDPOINT_SECRET`):

```rb
def post_stripe_webhook
  params = {
    type: 'checkout.session.completed',
    data: {
      object: {
        id:             Faker::Internet.uuid,
        metadata:       {
          request_payment_token: Faker::Internet.uuid
        },
        payment_status: 'paid',
        payment_link:   'plink_dfdasfasdff23fsdf2esd'
      }
    }
  }
  stripe_header = Stripe::Webhook::Signature.generate_header(
    Time.now,
    Stripe::Webhook::Signature.compute_signature(Time.now, JSON.dump(params), 'STRIPE_ENDPOINT_SECRET')
  )
  headers = { 'HTTP_STRIPE_SIGNATURE': stripe_header }
  post '/api/webhooks/payments/successful', params:, headers:, as: :json
end
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me:

```
describe('Stripe webhooks', () => {
    it('handles payment_intent.succeeded event', async () => {
        const paymentIntent = {
            id: 'pi_456',
            amount: 2000,
            // ..etc etc
        }

        const event = {
            id: 'evt_1',
            type: 'payment_intent.succeeded',
            data: { object: paymentIntent },
        }
        const payloadString = JSON.stringify(event)

        const header = Stripe.webhooks.generateTestHeaderString({
            payload: payloadString,
            secret: 'whsec_lorim_ipsum_etc_etc',
        })

        // endpoint of your running test server
        const response = await axios.post(`${SERVER_END_POINT}/webhook/stripe`, event, {
            headers: {
                'stripe-signature': header,
            },
        })

        expect(response.status).toBe(200)
        // etc..
    })
})
```

This requires installing and importing a stripe js lib:

```
import Stripe from 'stripe'
```

The handling code can be taken from here https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/quickstart

However do note, **if you parse JSON with your express server you must add this webhook route to your server BEFORE any json parsing libs** (eg `app.use(express.json())` or `app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '50mb' }))` for instance).

Or alternatively instruct express to treat the webhook route differently: `app.use('/webhook/stripe', express.raw({ type: 'application/json' }));`

It was also useful during development/testing to use the CLI.

first run this to intercept webhook traffic and route it to your local app: `stripe listen --forward-to localhost:4001/webhook/stripe`

and then run `stripe trigger invoice.payment_succeeded` to have test webhook events fired off.